# How does my having someone in mind when I learn help them?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, mitzvah, reward-punishment

Many times, as a merit for a recovery for someone sick or someone in need, I have been asked to have that person in mind when I learn.  In some places, they will put up a sign asking to have a certain person in mind, particularly if that person has made a donation to the organization where the learning is taking place.

If the request would be "please learn with more intensity than usual as a merit for this person" then I would understand how this could be a merit for them, as they are now the impetus and catalyst for my qualitative improvement in my learning.  But just "having them in mind" doesn't seem to do very much.

Does merely being cognizant of another person when you do a Mitzvah somehow transfer credit to that person?

Note: This question could be asked about any Mitzvah, but I chose learning because it is a common example that I see.

Comment: I know of no benefit from such concentration. If anything it is detrimental to your focus on the learning.

Comment: @DoubleAA That's my feeling as well, but פוק חזי מאי עמא דבר.

Comment: מוטב שיהיו לומדין ואל יהיו בטלים

Comment: @DoubleAA If they would be בטלים otherwise, then I think it would make a lot of sense.

Comment: I've always understood it as learning for that person's merit (i.e. instead of for one's own merit)

Comment: Good question!A fundamental belief of Jewish Faith is that we get rewarded for our good deeds and punished for our bad ones. "Passing around merit" would undermine this concept. As it says in Yigdal:גּוֹמֵל לְאִישׁ חֶסֶד כְּמִפְעָלוֹ, נוֹתֵן לְרָשָׁע רַע כְּרִשְׁעָתוֹ.

Answer (score 1):

From [this article](http://ohr.edu/ask_db/ask_main.php/211/Q4/):

> Some say that since the patient has inspired me (consciously or not)
>   to perform a mitzvah, a commandment, and has caused the one who prays
>   or studies Torah to draw closer to G-d, then the patient has direct
>   merit as a result of the prayer. Another way of understanding this is
>   the one who prays is binding himself to the patient, showing concern
>   and sharing the patient's pain. The Divine calculation now must take
>   into account not just the patient and his pain, but also all those who
>   are praying for him.

Answer (score 1):

[R' Natan Slifkin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natan_Slifkin) examined the issue of transferring *mitzva* credit to other people, in the course of a broader discussion of benefiting people who have passed away, in a memorial lecture for his mother-in-law, entitled "What Can One Do For Someone Who Has Passed Away?" It is available for download in essay form [here](http://www.rationalistjudaism.com/2014/02/what-can-one-do-for-someone-who-has.html).

R' Slifkin points out (p. 3) that the idea of transfer of *mitzva* credit is dependent on the mystical concept of the product of *mitzvot* being supernatural spiritual emanations. This mystical concept is rejected by rationalist schools of thought in favor of a more practical concept of what *mitzvot* accomplish: "According to [Rambam](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maimonides), mitzvos affect society, our intellects and our personalities; 
other authorities express the function of mitzvos as creating a relationship with God.
Either way, mitzvos do not produce spiritual energy, such that one could transfer this 
to others."

He cites (pp. 4 - 5) a collection of instances of [Geonim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geonim), [Rishonim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rishonim), and [Acharonim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acharonim) rejecting the idea of transferring mitzva credit and provides quotations of two Geonim, as cited by later authorities:

- [Rav Sherira Gaon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherira_Gaon), cited by the [Rashba](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shlomo_ben_Aderet) in his Responsa, [Vol. 7 #539](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1379&st=&pgnum=336&hilite=) (this and the next translation presumably by R' Slifkin, source links added for Mi Yodeya):

  > A person cannot merit someone else with reward; his elevation and greatness and 
  >   pleasure from the radiance of the Divine Presence is only in accordance with his deeds. Even if all the righteous people in the world were to seek mercy for him, and 
  >   all the righteous acts were to be done in his merit, it would be of no help to him…

However, most of the responsa is spent describing how another *can* help with their Mitzvos primarily by alleviating punishments through giving charity in the merit of the person or through a Tzadik praying for them. It then goes on to justify practices such as remembering the dead (Yizkor) based on this idea.

- [Rav Hai Gaon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hai_Gaon), cited by [Maharam Alashkar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moses_Alashkar) in his Responsa [#101](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1168&st=&pgnum=270&hilite=), which concerns the possibility of people selling their merits to each other:

  > These concepts are nonsense and one should not rely upon them. How can one 
  >   entertain the notion that the reward of good deeds performed by one person should 
  >   go to another person? Surely the verse states, “The righteousness of a righteous 
  >   person is on him,” ([Ezek. 18:20](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16116#v=20)) and likewise it states, “And the wickedness of a 
  >   wicked person is upon him.” Just as nobody can be punished on account of 
  >   somebody else’s sin, so too nobody can merit the reward of someone else. How 
  >   could one think that the reward for mitzvos is something that a person can carry 
  >   around with him, such that he can transfer it to another person?

In this, like the Rashba, he rejects transferring reward. He does not address punishments, however he says that it does help to support and pay for someone to learn Torah, as the act of paying or even better supporting through removing distractions is the cause of the reward.

Comment: I'm not sure this answers the question.

Comment: I don't know how someone can claim that the Rambam felt _mitzvos_ were _purely_ practical, in light of [Hilchos Teshuva 9](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/1509.htm).  It may be a side-benefit, but _mitzvos_ _clearly_ have metaphysical ramifications.

Comment: @yEz where do you see any metaphysical ramifications in that Rambam? all he says is that mitzvos deepen our understanding of God. See also http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/61018/intrinsic-value-of-mitzvot?s=1|1.3092. (This precisely was my intent with that question, although it seems to have mostly remain un-understood.

Comment: @mevaqesh did you start at the beginning of that chapter?  It is all about the material, this-worldly rewards that will result from keeping _mitzvos_, with no rational direct cause-effect relationship other than that G-d said so.

Comment: @yEz I certainly started at the beginning of the chapter. To reiterate I see him saying that mitzvos lead to intellectual perfection which opens to the doors to the world to come. For failing to perform them, God punishes.  There is no evidence from that Rambam, however, that a mitzvah is a sort of segulah; i.e. a discrete spiritual unit whose value is more than the sum of its parts. In other words, the value of a good deed is not the "shem mitzah" but rather inherent value of act on oneself and others. I.e. it helps on achieve shelmus. Through the shlemus, one can enter the world to come.

Comment: @yEz If, however, one could achieve the same results without performing the mitzvah, but by performin, for example, a very similar act, (assuming we are speaking of a mitzvah kiyumis, of course), then I see no evidence on the Rambam that there would be any chisaron; fault, with this. To further clarify, you are correct that in Rambam's conception reward and punishment is not a natural process, but obviously a supernatural one. Nevertheless, the benchmark used to evaluate who deserves reward can be one with shlemus. That is, there is no evidence from this Rambam that mitzvos are like special...

Comment: @yEz passcodes that allow one into the realm of reward, rather, one could freely interpret him (and back it up with his statements elsewhere) that the determinant for reward is not the mitzva, but rather the associated benefit. In this way the _role_ of mitzvos is not metaphysical, although obviously the _method of application_ of reward for said good deeds is non-natural.

Comment: @mevaqesh You ignored my point entirely.  I am not talking about next-worldly reward. I am talking about rain and crops.  How does your tefillin lead to precipitation?

Comment: @yEz I thought I addressed that directly by differentiating between the role of mitzvos (not metaphysical) and the application of their reward (supernatural). I will try explaining once more. Although indeed God intervenes supernaturally as a result of mitzvos, the role of the mitzvos is natural and even mundane. E.g. If I help someone out, that act is considered meritorious inasmuch as it helped him, and inasmuch as I acheieved shlemus. If I could theoretically perform a technical mitzvah without achieving any concrete results, to myself or others, then I see no evidence that according to

Comment: @yEz Rambam that act would be significant. To repeat I was responding to your comment (originally) not the quote in the answer. I was addressing metaphysical role of the mitzvos. It turns out that you seemed to be referring to the method of application of reward, whereas I was addressing whether the act of the mitzah itself contains inherent metaphysical significance. To conclude, regarding transferring merits, although it seems reasonable that Rambam agrees that there is no "natural" connection between deed, and result in this world, there is evidence that in his view reward in the afterlife

Comment: @yEz is a natural result of one's intellectual-moral-state (sh'lemus). Accordingly, if one were trying to perform an act on behalf of a dead person, it seems difficult to understand according to Rambam how that could benefit him.

Answer (score 1):

The Ramma in hilchos Tzedaka, Yoreh Deah siman 249 16 says 'the minhag to give tzedaka in honor of the dead during Yizkor is a minhag vasikin and it helps the nishama'. The Taz brings a Beis Yosef in hilchos Yom Hakipurim who quotes a Rokeach who explains that Hashem searches a person's heart and if it would be that the dead person would be alive he would give tzedaka himself, if he had money etc. But if one gives in honor of a rasha, it does not work.

This opinion seems to say it is not a transference of schar, but a way to get Hashem to judge the dead man as if he did it too.

Another perspective. In Emes Liyaakov on Shulchan Aruch Yoreh Deah siman 246 footnote 128 he writes that it seems to him when someone learns in honor of a dead person the actual schar of learning goes to the dead person while the one who actually did the learning gets schar of gemilas chessed. But he adds this only works if every time he says the yehi ratzon etc or says that the learning should be for the dead person, as opposed to a son learning for a father where the schar goes to the father by default without speaking it out.

This opinion clearly holds a transference of schar takes place.

Comment: Interesting, this provides an earlier source (the Emes Liyaakov) than what Natan Slifkin found.

Comment: @Yishai not sure what you mean. Please elaborate?

Comment: I remember a story, yes a story, about the Gra who couldn't find an esrog. One rich man had one and told the Gra he can have it but only if the schar goes to him, the rich man. The Gra accepted happily and said he was waiting his whole life to do a mitzvah for its own sake with no thoughts of reward. I don't understand this story on many levels. One point is if you can actually trade away or give away schar, shouldn't he have been able to do any mitzvah with a tnai not to get schar?

Comment: One more point, similar to my last comment. The mishna in avos says to do mitzvos shelo al menas likabel pras, and while this is different than al menas shelo likabel pras, still we see we are all, on some level, supposed to be removed from the schar involved, and yet we certainly get schar. So how could actually thinking about transferring schar help?

Comment: In Issac Moses's answer he references an essay by Slifkin that puts the earliest mention about 75 years later.

Comment: @Yishai Im having trouble getting to that article, but it seems he is quoting geonim on the subject. The Emes Liyaakov I am quoting is from Reb Yaakov Kaminetsky.

Comment: In that case, never mind. That would be about 75 years later.