# Effect of mitzvos of ordinary people

Tags: mitzvah, mysticism-kabbalah

Is there a source in the *rishonim* or before, where it says that no matter on what spiritual level the person is, his *mitzvah* will have a major effect in the spiritual worlds?

Comment: In the Kabbalah of the Rishonim they only discuss the effect of a Mitzva, not the effect of your Kavanna while doing the Mitzva. The latter is mostly introduced by the Arizal.

Comment: @HaLeiVi so is there a source which interprets an earlier source to mean that this happens regardless of the spiritual level of the doer?

Answer (score 1):

The Rambam in Hilchos Teshuva 7:7 brings the novel concept that the context of your life defines the value of a Mitzvah done within it. A person who hasn't done Teshuva can do Mitzvos all he wants and Hashem rips them up in his face. Whereas a day later if the person has change the context of his life and done Teshuva, his Mitzvos are joyously accepted. 
כמה מעולה מעלת התשובה אמש היה זה מובדל מה' אלהי ישראל שנאמר עונותיכם היו מבדילים ביניכם לבין אלהיכם צועק ואינו נענה שנאמר כי תרבו תפלה וגו' ועושה מצות וטורפין אותן בפניו שנאמר מי בקש זאת מידכם רמוס חצרי מי גם בכם ויסגר דלתים וגו' והיום הוא מודבק בשכינה שנאמר ואתם הדבקים בה' אלהיכם צועק ונענה מיד שנאמר והיה טרם יקראו ואני אענה ועושה מצות ומקבלין אותן בנחת ושמחה
Therefore I would say it is quite the opposite of what you are looking for; the value of a Mitzvah depends very much on the performer's "spiritual level".

Comment: This seems like more of a comment to the question than an answer. (Since the OP was looking for one thing, and as noted, you provided the opposite.) Consider turning this answer into a comment.

Comment: This doesn't contradict the argument that the OP is looking to support. The fact that the mitzvos of some people are greater than others doesn't mean that the lowest of them isn't major in its effects.